# Is there a way to access history of Dolphin app browser on android from another application?

Tags: android, dolphin-browser

This is done without root access. Is there a public content provider URI of dolphin app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the Dolphin Browser doesn't have an SDK or a ContentProvider that you can access the data. The Android Browser is open-sourced and has more openness toward 3rd-Party Devs, unlike Dolphin.